# update position of the buttons tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, button, frame

I am looking for a way to fix the locations of the buttons in my app.
I am new to programing and I hope you can help me.
When I delete one of the items on the list than the buttons should to update their position. I mean if you delete one on the middle than the rest from the bottom will go 1 position up.
Also when I am loading list from txt file than the items in my app should to be destroyed.

````
items = [0]

def savefile():
    with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
       f.truncate(0)

       for b in items:
            f.write(b['text'] + "\n")
    
def loadfile():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        text = f.readlines()
        for line in text:
            loaditem(line)

def loaditem(txt):
    global counter
    button_text = txt.strip()
    b = tk.Button(frame1, text = button_text,font=("Arial", 12),height=2)   
    b.place(x = 0, y = counter * 50 + 0)
    items.append(b)
    b.config(command = partial(delete_button, b))
    counter += 1

def additem(*args):
    global counter
    button_text = l1.get()
    b = tk.Button(frame1, text = button_text, font=("Arial", 12), height=2)
    b.place( x = 0, y = counter * 50 + 0)
    items.append(b)
    b.config(command = partial(delete_button, b))
    counter += 1

def delete_button(button,*args):
    global counter
    index = items.index(button)
    b = (items[index])
    b.destroy()

l1 = tk.Entry(root, width=24, font=("Arial", 12))
l1.place(height=50,x=20,y=80)

frame1= tk.Frame(root,width=300,height=600,bg="grey")
frame1.place(x=20, y=150)```
````

Comment: If button is in variable `b` then use `b.place_forget()` and then place it again.

Comment: can you tell me a bit more please.

Comment: `place_forget()` is a method that removes your widget from the window, and to place it again you need to use `place()`. You also have `grid_forget()` when using `grid()`. This is generally a better method then `destroy()`

Comment: Please create a _complete_ [mcve], and preferably one with some hard-coded data rather than requiring an external file. You've provided several functions but nothing calls those functions.

Comment: @BokiX: the forget method isn't better than destroy -- they do two completely different things. The one that is better is the one that does what you actually need to do, either destroying the widget or just hiding it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `place` instead of `grid` or `pack`? If you're creating a vertical list of widgets, `pack` will be the easiest solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes i have a reason. This is for my assignment and teacher told me to use 'place' instead of them.

Comment: If you must use `place`, I think the only solution is that you will have to recalculate the x/y coordinates of every widget below the one you are deleting.